# change the font of sharePoint list item before updating

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010

how can we change the font of the string in the sharepoint list item update:

```
item["Comments"]="Commented";
item.update();
```

i am trying to change the font size of "Commented" to 'Calibri'. any quick help friends.

Comment: Change the css of an item in the list isn't an "easy thing". You'll have to work with XSLT or JSLink, here is a way to do : http://www.contentmaster.com/sharepoint-2010/conditional-formatting-of-list-views-for-sharepoint-2010-changing-the-font-colour/

Answer (score 0):

You should change the CSS.

Make a custom.css file and add a reference to the masterpage.
Example:

```
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Custom/custom.css%>" runat="server"/>
```

In the example the css file is located in the site collection his style library in the folder custom.

The change will affect the whole site collection since you edit the masterpage. If you desire to change only the font on one page you could use inline style. However this is a real pain in the ass to manage and I wouldn't recommend.

If you need help with the content of the css file let me know.